# how would I write linq query that would display user name instead of userID in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

how would I write linq query that would display user name instead of userID in a gridview.

```
var q = from u in entities.problems
                       join a in entities.my_aspnet_membership on u.user_id equals a.userId
                       join c in entities.my_aspnet_users on a.userId equals c.id
                       where c.id == a.userId
                       select new { u.problem_id, c.name, u.problem_description, u.problem_reported_datetime, u.problem_history};
```

What I am looking is when uasing login in the webiste only to see problems they submitted.

Answer (score 2):

Bind only those columns needed to display the result. Turn off the `AutoGeneratedColumns` and add `BoundField` columns.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of issues with your query:

1. Where part (`where c.id == a.userId`) does not make sense.
2. Join with membership table - why is this needed? This join could potential give you multiple rows for one problem (if user has multiple roles) - eliminate if it's not needed.

For example,

```
var q = from u in entities.problems
                       join c in entities.my_aspnet_users on u.user_id equals c.id
                       select new { 
                              u.problem_id, c.name, u.problem_description, 
                              u.problem_reported_datetime, u.problem_history
                       };
```

This will give you all problems along with user name - bind the grid column with `"name"` column.

If you want to list the problems for only logged in user then you have to add where part such as `where u.user_id = currentUserId` where `currentUserId` variable will hold the value of logged in user.

Comment: Thanks,  I used part of your solutions added
                        var currentName = Page.User.Identity.Name; then added this for the where c.name == currentName. Not a clean piece of code but time sensitive right now.